# Remove numeric array keys from multidimensional array like [0] , [1]

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to remove the numeric keys from multi dimensional array

My code is

```
    $arr = array(
        array(
            'id' => 100,
            'Started' => '2016-03-03 00:00:00',
            'ended' => '2016-03-03 00:00:00' 
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 101,
            'Started' => '2017-03-03 00:00:00',
            'ended' => '2017-03-03 00:00:00'             
        )
    );

  echo"<pre>";
  print_r($array);
  exit();
```

and its giving this OUTPUT 
[image]

Please help . What change i need to do in code so i can remove the numeric keys ?

[image]

Comment: your output and output needed are same.

Comment: You know that every array element needs a key? If your question is just about outputing it like this you have to do it with some loops. There is no build-in function for this specific case.

Comment: Oops! sorry i uploaded the same image . Now its fine .. any idea ? how to remove array numeric keys ?

Comment: Nope PHP automatically defines the key in ascending order if you've not manually defined the key

Comment: actually i need to convert into json and when i convert into json it also show keys . which is not needed in web service .

Comment: [You might be looking for json_encode() function of PHP](https://3v4l.org/V4gTr)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because because the question is based on a misunderatanding and there is no code to fix.